# FileNotFoundError when generating LaTeX PDF with Django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, latex, pdflatex

Working from the example given [here](https://blog.sevenbyte.org/2014/09/23/generating-pdfs-with-django-and-latex.html), I'm trying to get a Django app to generate a PDF from a template written in LaTeX. Note that I have not gotten to the stage of populating the LaTeX template file with values from the database. It currently has 'hard-coded' content, I'm just trying to get the PDF generation working first.

## views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import Context
from django.template.loader import get_template
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
import tempfile

def pdf(request):
    context = Context({})
    template = get_template('cv.tex')
    rendered_tpl = template.render(context).encode('utf-8')  
    with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as tempdir:  
        # Create subprocess, supress output with PIPE and
        # run latex twice to generate the TOC properly.
        # Finally read the generated pdf.
        for i in range(2):
            process = Popen(
                ['pdflatex', '-output-directory', tempdir],
                stdin=PIPE,
                stdout=PIPE,
            )
            process.communicate(rendered_tpl)
        with open(os.path.join(tempdir, 'texput.pdf'), 'rb') as f:
            pdf = f.read()
    r = HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf')  
    r.write(pdf)
    return r
```

But when I go to the URL I've pointed at the view, I get the following error.

```
Internal Server Error: /cv.pdf
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 149, in get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 147, in get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\LThorburn\Documents\Dropbox\Code\lt.co\cv\views.py", line 45, in pdf
    with open(os.path.join(tempdir, 'texput.pdf'), 'rb') as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\LTHORB~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmpik2iw24w\\texput.
pdf'
```

I'm not very familiar with handling temporary files. What do I need to do?

## EDIT

In response to @stovfl's suggestion below, I replaced `with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as tempdir:` with `with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory(dir='.') as tempdir:`. This resulted in a new error below:

```
C:\Users\LThorburn\Documents\Dropbox\Code\lt.co\cv\views.py:33: RemovedInDjango110Warning: render() must be called with
a dict, not a Context.
  rendered_tpl = template.render(context).encode('utf-8')

pdflatex: Unknown archive file size.
pdflatex: Data: resume
pdflatex: Unknown archive file size.
pdflatex: Data: resume
[FAIL] File .\tmppml24lmd\texput.pdf not found
Internal Server Error: /cv.pdf
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\LThorburn\Documents\Dropbox\Code\lt.co\cv\views.py", line 51, in pdf
    with open(os.path.join(tempdir, 'texput.pdf'), 'rb') as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '.\\tmppml24lmd\\texput.pdf'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 149, in get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 147, in get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\LThorburn\Documents\Dropbox\Code\lt.co\cv\views.py", line 52, in pdf
    pdf = f.read()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tempfile.py", line 685, in __exit__
    self.cleanup()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tempfile.py", line 689, in cleanup
    _shutil.rmtree(self.name)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\shutil.py", line 478, in rmtree
    return _rmtree_unsafe(path, onerror)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\shutil.py", line 377, in _rmtree_unsafe
    onerror(os.rmdir, path, sys.exc_info())
  File "C:\Python34\lib\shutil.py", line 375, in _rmtree_unsafe
    os.rmdir(path)
OSError: [WinError 145] The directory is not empty: '.\\tmppml24lmd'
[08/Mar/2017 22:15:50] "GET /cv.pdf HTTP/1.1" 500 96729
```

Comment: Full traceback please.

Comment: Most likely your error is with the `process = Popen()` I got an error pointing to that line of code when I ran your snippet.

Comment: @Guillaume Full Traceback added.

Comment: pdflatex outputs errors, but you're throwing them away. You will probably find useful debug output if you capture the output of `process.communicate()`

Answer (score 2):

#### initial answer when error involved `.log` file, problem has changed

I do not think the problem is due to 'Tempfile' because your error deals with a `.log` file and not a randomly created temporary directory like your code shows.
When I run the following code:

```
with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as tempdir:
    print(os.path.join(tempdir, 'test.txt'))
    with open(os.path.join(tempdir, 'test.txt'),"w") as tmpfile:
        tmpfile.write("test.txt")
```

I get the following output:
`/var/folders/xj/zz73z72j0bb80kt2x6z8sfq5p7zwwg/T/tmpfhk0qwjf/test.txt`

Notice that the directory is random, not the file.

You appear to be having a problem accessing a randomly generated log file.

Also, you may want to consider a few improvements to your code:

1. You are not prepared for the `pdflatex` command to fail. You assume the output file is always generated.
2. You are running a subprocesses in an http handler, which is generally not a good idea. One main reason is the command may take too long and the client will timeout. Think about using tools like 'celery`.

A more detailed traceback will help track down the bug further.

#### Update #1

Can you try to print the STDOUT and STDERR of the `pdflatex` command when the error occurs by replace:

```
 process.communicate(rendered_tpl)
 with open(os.path.join(tempdir, 'texput.pdf'), 'rb') as f:
        pdf = f.read()
```

with:

```
out,err = process.communicate(rendered_tpl)
try:
    fn = os.path.join(tempdir, 'texput.pdf')
    f = open(fn)
    pdf = f.read()
    f.close()
except FileNotFoundError:
    raise FileNotFoundError("Could not find {}.\nSTDOUT from pdflatex:{}.\nSTDERR from pdflatex:{}\n",format(fn,out,err))
```

#### Update #2

Ok it is now clear that the command is not producing the file you are looking for and giving you the error `LaTeX Error: File 'res.cls' not found. ... there is probably something wrong with the class file.`

It looks like you need to download the `res` class file for the application to work correctly. You can find more information [here](http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=27137).

Comment: I suspect you're on to something. When I try your update, I get a whole lot of text, but most relevant of which is `LaTeX Error: File 'res.cls' not found. ... there is probably something wrong with the class file.`. At the moment my class file is just in the template directory with `cv.tex`. Where should I put it? (Or do I could I just combine it with the `.tex` file?)

Comment: Looks like you have to install that latex package onto your server. See [this](http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=27137) forum post for details.

Comment: Thanks, I replaced my `.tex` file with a much simpler one, using the default article documentclass, and it all works now. I did have the `res` file in the same folder as the template, but it seems that isn't the right place. Regardless, I've got it working now, so thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

> Third follow-up:

Unexpected result:

1. Please **update** the code in your Question after changeing it local.
   So we can compare Output, Traceback!
2. Please add a `exit(1)` in `except` block, so we not disturbed with folloup errors:

   `except os.error:
       print('[FAIL] File %s not found\nEXIT(1)' % path2pdf)
       exit(1)`
3. Please, as long we are testing set the loop count to 1

   ```
   for i in range(1):
   ```
4. New, error!
   Have you doublechecked inserting `dir='.'` are the only changes?

> C:\Users\LThorburn\Documents\Dropbox\Code\lt.co\cv\views.py:33:
>       RemovedInDjango110
>       **Warning: render() must be called with a dict, not a Context.**
>       rendered_tpl = template.render(context).encode('utf-8')

The example you pointed to, uses:
    `context = Context({ 'content': entry.content, })`
you use
    `context = Context({})`
Have to dig into this, but as this Warning did not show up before,
I guess you have changed anything else.

5. This could be a subsequent fault from Django Warning

> pdflatex: Unknown archive file size.
>       pdflatex: Data: resume

6. Output from `process.communicate(rendered_tpl)`
   Have you ever tried pdflatex from a *command console*?
   What gives:
   **C: pdflatex -output-directory - < cv.tex**

---

> Second follow-up:

After updating your Question with a new Traceback, which points to the pdf file,
we have to verify why `pdflatex` does not create the pdf file.

First we check `Process` have write privileges.

Change your
    `with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as tempdir:`
to
    `with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory(dir='.') as tempdir:`

This moves the tempdir from OS location to the current dirctory your script ist running.
Please comment as this behaves the same.

Comment: Alas I don't, I get the exception: `[FAIL] File C:\Users\LTHORB~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp15_vu4ha\texput.pdf not found`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, see my edit in the question.

Comment: Thanks for all your help, sorry I could only award the bounty to one person.